# presentViewController doesnt "see" my viewControllers

Tags: ios, presentmodalviewcontroller

MainMenuViewController presents BonusViewController modally. I want to Dismiss BonusViewController then display a new BonusViewController, effectively "resetting" BonusViewController.

Im using notifications to call this method in MainMenuViewController

```
-(void)resetBonus{



    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    [self presentViewController: BonusViewController animated:NO completion:nil];


}
```

I expected BonusViewController to be auto-detected as I was typing it in the presentViewController call above but it was not and none of my viewControllers show up as I type which Im assuming means im doing this all wrong. Do I have to initialize the VC or allocate it before I can present it like this? Or can I even do this at all since im using storyboards?

I also tried this though I believe this method is deprecated

```
-(void)resetBonus{

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [self presentModalViewController: BonusViewController animated:NO ]; 

}
```

[image]

Did what Sumanth suggested but I get this message now:

[image]

so now I m doing :

```
#import "BonusViewController.h

....

-(void)resetBonus
{
BonusViewController  *bonus = [[BonusViewController alloc]init];
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
[self presentModalViewController: bonus animated:NO ];

}
```

the errors are all gone but when BonusViewController is presented the display is solid black, i can hear the sounds going but cant see anything on the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should allocate and initialize the viewcontroller and present that using `presentModalViewController` write like this

```
BonusViewController  *bonus = [[BonusViewController alloc]init]; 
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
[self presentModalViewController: bonus animated:NO ];
```

Comment: Ok did that but got a new message, any thoughts ? Edit above*

Comment: you should import the BonusViewController to your class. use this in your .h or .m class `#import BonusViewController.h`

Comment: Thanks for your help, going with a simpler over all solution for now and will re-vist this issue again when time permits

Comment: I didnt see xib file in the picture you attached. If your are using xib to this class you should initiate the class like this `BonusViewController  *bonus = [[BonusViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"YOUR XIB NAME WITHOUT .XIB" bundle:nil];` EX:`BonusViewController  *bonus = [[BonusViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"BonusViewController" bundle:nil];`

Comment: Also, you may run into problems using presentModalViewController since it's deprecated in iOS 6.  You should use [self presentViewController: bonus animated:NO completion:nil]; instead and save yourself some headaches...take a look at Dhara's answer, which is actually the most current correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Also dont forget to write #import "BonusViewController.h" in .h file

```
BonusViewController  *objBonus = [[BonusViewController alloc]init]; 
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
[self presentViewController:objBonus animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

You need to create and object of the viewcontroller and you are directly passing the viewcontroller which is not possible

Comment: +1 for using [self presentViewController:objBonus animated:YES completion:NULL];

Answer (score 0):

```
#import "BonusViewController.h"
-(void)resetBonus
    {
    BonusViewController  *BonusViewController = [[BonusViewController alloc]init];
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
        [self presentViewController: BonusViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
    }
```

Set Both of animated is **NO**

EDIT : `#import "BonusViewController.h"`

Comment: Tried this too but got same massage as Sumanth's suggestion above

Answer (score 0):

Im sure the answers given were correct but I could not get them to work properly. For some reason BonusViewController  seems to be displayed as I can hear the sounds going but the screen is black and nothing is displayed visually.

I ended up doing the below for now in the intrest of time but this isnt the smooth effect I was really going for.

I have to re-visit this when I have more time to figure out a better way to do it.

```
-(void)endBonus
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
        [self performSelector:@selector(resetBonus) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];
    }];

}
-(void)resetBonus
{
 [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"segueToBonus" sender: self];
}
```